# Amazon Product Advertising API - PHP FATAL ERROR

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

For a few days I'm trying to connect to Amazon Product Advertising API using PHP.
I've tried both SDK and none SDK and nothing helps.

I want to share a none sdk code and maybe get your help on why i'm getting an error.

```html
<?php

/**
 * Copyright 2019 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */
include ("aws.php");
$searchItemRequest = new SearchItemsRequest ();
$searchItemRequest->PartnerType = "Associates";
// Put your Partner tag (Store/Tracking id) in place of Partner tag
$searchItemRequest->PartnerTag = "***";
$searchItemRequest->Keywords = "Harry";
$searchItemRequest->SearchIndex = "All";
$searchItemRequest->Resources = ["Images.Primary.Small","ItemInfo.Title","Offers.Listings.Price"];
$host = "webservices.amazon.com";
$path = "/paapi5/searchitems";
$payload = json_encode ($searchItemRequest);
//Put your Access Key in place of <ACCESS_KEY> and Secret Key in place of <SECRET_KEY> in double quotes
$awsv4 = new AwsV4 ("***", "***");
$awsv4->setRegionName("us-east-1");
$awsv4->setServiceName("ProductAdvertisingAPI");
$awsv4->setPath ($path);
$awsv4->setPayload ($payload);
$awsv4->setRequestMethod ("POST");
$awsv4->addHeader ('content-encoding', 'amz-1.0');
$awsv4->addHeader ('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
$awsv4->addHeader ('host', $host);
$awsv4->addHeader ('x-amz-target', 'com.amazon.paapi5.v1.ProductAdvertisingAPIv1.SearchItems');
$headers = $awsv4->getHeaders ();
$headerString = "";
foreach ( $headers as $key => $value ) {
    $headerString .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\r\n";
}
$params = array (
        'http' => array (
            'header' => $headerString,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $payload
        )
    );
$stream = stream_context_create ( $params );

$fp = @fopen ( 'https://'.$host.$path, 'rb', false, $stream );

if (! $fp) {
    throw new Exception ( "Exception Occured" );
}
$response = @stream_get_contents ( $fp );
if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception ( "Exception Occured" );
}
echo $response;

class SearchItemsRequest {
    public $PartnerType;
    public $PartnerTag;
    public $Keywords;
    public $SearchIndex;
    public $Resources;
}
?>
```

Error is:

root@difmode:/var/www/html/cms# php index.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Exception Occured in /var/www/html/cms/index.php:56
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in /var/www/html/cms/index.php on line 56

Answer (score 0):

If I counted your lines correctly, then the error is thrown by your code:

```
$fp = @fopen ( 'https://'.$host.$path, 'rb', false, $stream );

if (! $fp) {
    throw new Exception ( "Exception Occured" );
}
```

Basically your $fp is empty. Why, well remove the mutes (`@`) from your code and you will see the errors.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the mutes. And received the error:  

PHP Warning:  fopen(https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/searchitems): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
 in /var/www/html/cms/index.php on line 53
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Exception Occured in /var/www/html/cms/index.php:56
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/cms/index.php on line 56

Comment: HTTP/1.1 401 - this means you are not authorized to access the content, this means you need to authenticate first. looks like you are already adding the auth headers, but something must be wrong with either how you generate them, or with your credentials/access setup on aws.

Comment: I've took the access, security and partner tag directly from Amazon Associates Centeral and add them to my code.